# Vector allocation when declaring struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

You can create a C++ structure with an array within:

```
struct foo{
    int bar[42];
};
```

What I would like to do is:

```
struct foo{
    std::vector<int> bar(42);
};
```

Of course this doesn't compile, but you get the intent. I'm aware of .reserve() and the like,
but I would like to have the space already allocated when declaring a `foo`.

The reason is that I'm supposed to alter a rather complicated Perl script which is generating C code with arrays within structs. These arrays should be replaced by `std::vector`s. The script subsequently initializes the arrays depending on an XML file and I would rather not mess around with `push_back` in the script since the structures are deeply nested (structs of arrays and arrays of structs). The sizes of the arrays do of course vary.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to replace the array with std::vector but still want to have static memory allocation (ie allocate resources at compile-time). As far as I know, std::vector allocates resources dynamically, implying that the answers stated below using the constructors will allocate memory at run-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a constructor:

```
struct foo{
    std::vector<int> bar;
    foo() : bar(32) {}
};
```

Memory for the vector will automatically be allocated when creating an instance. The initialization list initializes members before the constructor body executes.

Answer (score 3):

Add a constructor and use the initializer list:

```
struct foo {
    foo() : bar(42) {}
    std::vector<int> bar;
};
```

If your compiler supports C++11 features use [`std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

```
struct foo {
    std::array<int, 42> bar;
};
```

Or [`boost::array<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/array.html) if C++11 is not available and boost is permitted.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that C++11 also allows initialization at the point of declaration.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers have explained how to do what you want to do, but I think they've missed the important part of explaining why. The thing that you need to grasp is that `struct` in C++ is simply a near-synonym for `class` with the *only* difference being that a struct defaults to having public members and a class defaults to having private. You could replace every instance of `class` in your code with

```
struct X
{
    private:
    ...
}
```

and it would work exactly the same and *vice versa* for replacing `structs` with `class`. This means that just as you would use a constructor to do what you want with a class, you use a constructor with your struct:

```
struct foo
{
    std::vector<int> bar;
    foo() : bar(42) {}
}
```

This [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) for `std::vector`, btw, also take a couple more arguments with the second being the value to fill your vector with so you could do `foo() : bar(42, -1) {}` to fill your vector with values of `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the size of the vector(i.e. call `std::vector`'s constructor) in the constructor of the structure(preferably in its initialization list).

Like so:

```
struct foo{
    foo() : bar(42) {}
    std::vector<int> bar;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor, as suggested in other answers. But I must fix you:

1. Space will be "already allocated" *after* definition (in case of using constructor);
2. You should never use .reserve(), only .resize() (**before you understand difference**);
3. You can call .resize() after declaration safely and almost without overhead (instead of using constructor). **But anyway, learn and use constructor.**

Comment: What does 1 mean? A declaration doesn't allocate any memory. Also, what you you mean "never use `reserve()`"? Why not? Also, 3) is wrong, the intiailization list should be preferred.

Comment: 1) he said "I would like to have the space already allocated when declaring", I just fixed words; 2) he doesn't know constructors, are you think he will use .reserve() properly? 3) I know and append that to answer at once

Comment: You're missunderstanding what "declaration" means. A class declaration is `struct foo`. What he has is a definition. Neither allocate memory.  I'm not saying he knows what reserve does, but "never use reserve" is bad advice. A good advice is "learn what reserve does". Definitely not "never do it". 3) Again, you missunderstand what "declaration" means.

Comment: Never use `reserve` just strikes me as bad advice.

Comment: 1. I didn't say that he wrote declaration in question. I said about declaration, yes, declaration which he didn't wrote in question but will write in code. His words means that some memory is allocated before object construction, this have no sense and I fixed WORDS. 2. Read second to end of line. With attention. 3. Third I wrote for clarify that this method ALSO works in his code. I advised him to use constructor, but his case allows to don't learn constructors.